# How to keep the automatically added argparse help argument, but remove -h from it so I can use that option for another argument

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

The automatically added help argument has option strings `-h` and `--help`. I want to keep the help argument for `--help` but remove `-h` from it, so I can use that option string for another argument.

I think there has to be a better way than to completely remove the help argument with [`add_help=False`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#add-help) just to add it again with `--help` and `action="help"` immediately afterwards, right? Maybe I can modify the existing help argument's option strings?

---

By the way, regarding "Don't remove `-h` because users expect it to be an alias for `--help`": That's a fair argument. However, while having a quick look through my local binaries, I couldn't find any command which uses `-h` to show the help message other than `fdisk`. (That doesn't mean that there aren't a few more, of course.) Even more: Many commands use `-h` for something completely different, see `ls`, `cd`, `df` and `diff` to name some of them.

Comment: Keep in mind that users (especially folks coming from pre-GNU platforms where `--help` wasn't a thing) will often *assume* they can run `yourprogram -h` for help. If it doesn't give them help, that'll be confusing. (After all, if someone *knew the usage already*, they wouldn't need help).

Comment: I second what Charles says. The [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) is important. If it does anything, `-h` should be the same as `--help` and should show some basic usage information.

Comment: It is possible to add your own argument that uses '-h', but you have to change the `confilct_handler`.  The alternate handler replaces  the original '-h' with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

The conflict_handler route:

```
In [5]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(conflict_handler='resolve')                             
In [6]: parser.add_argument('-h','--handle',help='handle foobar',default='foo');               

In [7]: parser.print_help()                                                                    
usage: ipython3 [--help] [-h HANDLE]

optional arguments:
  --help                show this help message and exit
  -h HANDLE, --handle HANDLE
                        handle foobar
```

`resolve` just changed the '-h', not the '--help'.

Using the new '-h':

```
In [8]: parser.parse_args('-h bar'.split())                                                    
Out[8]: Namespace(handle='bar')
```

Since abbreviations are still allowed '-help' with one dash gives unexpected results:

```
In [9]: parser.parse_args('-help'.split())                                                     
Out[9]: Namespace(handle='elp')
```

Correct help:

```
In [10]: parser.parse_args('--help'.split())                                                   
usage: ipython3 [--help] [-h HANDLE]

optional arguments:
  --help                show this help message and exit
  -h HANDLE, --handle HANDLE
                        handle foobar
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3327: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Look at the code for the `_handle_conflict_resolve` method to see exactly what it does.

Comment: You could use the default 'error' during initial construction, and once you are sure the other arguments aren't producing conflicts, switch to resolve.  We are dealing with development bugs, not runtime ones.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe I can modify the existing help argument's option strings?

Just to mention it, very hacky way to modify the existing arguments:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>>> parser._actions[0].option_strings.remove("-h")
>>> parser._option_string_actions.pop("-h")
_HelpAction(option_strings=['--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [--help]

optional arguments:
  --help  show this help message and exit
```

By the way, instead of

```py
parser._actions[0].option_strings.remove("-h")
parser._option_string_actions.pop("-h")
```

you could also make use of `_handle_conflict_resolve`:

```py
parser._handle_conflict_resolve(None, [("-h", parser._actions[0])])
```

> I think there has to be a better way than to completely remove the help argument with [`add_help=False`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#add-help) just to add it again with `--help` and `action="help"` immediately afterwards

And just for completeness, here is how that would work:

```
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser, SUPPRESS
>>> parser = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
>>> parser.add_argument("--help", action="help", default=SUPPRESS, help="show this help message and exit")
_HelpAction(option_strings=['--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [--help]

optional arguments:
  --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: `resolve` does essentially this - removing the 'offending' flag string from `option_strings`.